# Запрос на увеличение числа в записи?

Tags: php, mysql

нужно просто увеличить число в конкретной ячейке, делать это через два запроса мне кажется затратно немного, возможно ли как-то это через 1-ин запрос сделать?

Comment: а как вы сейчас делаете?

Comment: беру одним запросом число из ячейки, увеличиваю, потом вторым запросом вставляю, смысл код писать?

Comment: что бы понять зачем вы "берёте число из ячейки".

Comment: затем чтобы увеличить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то типа такого?

```
UPDATE catalog SET price = price * 1.05 WHERE category = 1
```

Comment: увеличить на 1, т.е. вместо * 1.05 поставлю +1, спасибо!

Comment: пожалуйста :)